# Why does my server return a 500 internal error when I do a DB query in a loop for xxxx+ times?

Tags: php, internal-server-error

This may be a silly question, but I'm curious:

When I loop a db query a *ridiculous* (10000+) amount of times, my server returns a 500 internal error.

I'm *not* including anything like this in any sort of app, I'm just completely curious.

EDIT:

Few things i forgot to mention:

Time limit on the script has been set to infinity.

The script actually still does all the db queries, even when the error is returned.

The error shows up after a short while, not straight away.

And once the error is returned, I cannot access any other page on my server for a good couple of mins (as if its frozen, and has to re-boot?)...

I'm also on shared host...

Comment: 500 error most-likely means there was a PHP error. Find out what the PHP error was and you'll have your answer.

Comment: right, and it might be a time limit problem, that's why I asked if it takes a lot of time to run.. it could be something to solve with http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: @mishu Yup, after a while. Forgot to mention, the script actually still completes, even after the error shows up.

Comment: @mishu And it cant be a time-limit problem because I've set that to infinity.

Comment: Guys, forgot to mention a few things. Check my edit please. xD

Comment: Can't it be a server protection? If you are unable to access your site for some time, maybe you are blocked for some specific rules about scripting time limit

Comment: @nav_nav Do you have access to the error log?  Are there any entries there related to the script you are attempting to run?

Comment: @chapkom I have checked the error logs, and nothing related to the script shows up. I think the issue could relate in some way to Marco Pace's comment.

Comment: If it is not the time limit, it sounds like you hit the memory limit. Check your memory_limit in php.ini.

Comment: Btw, what web server software are you running? It's quite strange that you do not get more details from your logs.

Comment: I'm almost thinking it's an HTTP Request timeout, but that should return HTTP 408, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlfredGodoy It's not the mem limit because I've just set the memory to 5gb and its still showing up. I think its a limit that the hosting provider have set. I don't have the specs of the server as I'm on shared host (with GoDaddy).

Comment: you have a deleted answer which tells this was a hosting limit. It's a fair answer; you should consider undeleting it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting `500` then there is like a `PHP` error you are not seeing .. you can use this to find out the error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
set_time_limit(0) ;
```

You can also do this if you don't have permission to set the option above

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

I hope it helps